# Javascript callback, Where to put return to prevent executing the next block

Tags: javascript, callback

I have the following Javascript code.

I want func1 to execute and guarantee that it does not execute the next section "if (!param1.hello)" block, if params1.hi does not exist. I feel like this code will have 5 possible outcome

1. Hi does not exist and returns before it calls the callback console.log('do something1')
2. Hi does not exist and returns after it calls the callback console.log('do something1')
3. Hi does not exist but hello also does not exist. So execute hello block first and returns before it calls the callback console.log('do something2')
4. Hi does not exist but hello also does not exist. So execute hello block first and returns after it calls the callback console.log('do something2')
5. console.log('do something1') and console.log('do something2') both get printed

No matter what, 'here is the final' is not printed.
Is my assumption right? And how can I gaurantee that the flow is *execute hi section first. *callback is always called before it returns *minimize execution time

```
function func1(param1) {
    if (!param1.hi) {
        logging.fire('hi does not exist', () => {
            console.log('do something1');
        });
        return;
    } 
    if (!param1.hello) {
        logging.fire('hello does not exist', () => {
            console.log('do something2');
        });
        return;
    }

    console.log('here is the final');
    return;
}

const logging = {
    fire: (event, callback) => {
        console.log('event fired: ' + event);
        return callback && callback();
    }
}

func1({})
```

Comment: if `param1.hi` and `param1.hello` both exist, 'here is the final' would be executed. if you want to make sure that only one of the `if` blocks is executed, replace your second `if` with an `else if`

Comment: @Prokzy It won`t. That return statement is outside of the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Let`s try another example.
The printout is :

```
> "event fired: hi does not exist"
> "event fired: event in event"
> "event in event fired"
> "do something1"
> "something1 outside"
```

I am not the expert so it may not be precise but for this kind of concurrency, when the event is fired, the "context"(conceptually) will switch to the action of the event. So when 'hi does not exist' triggered, the action in the callback is executed first, and we see that it is followed by 'event in event'. When the printout of "event in event fired" is done, it returns to the callback of 'hi does not exist' and then back to the original "context": func1.
This is the reason that "something1 outside" is the last one to appear.

In the cases that the callback takes huge time to execute, I really have no idea. For example, if the language/environments allow actions like "sleep" in the callback that hangs up the current queue of actions, the func1 might finish executing before all these callbacks.

---

```
function func1(param1) {
    if (!param1.hi) {
        logging.fire('hi does not exist', () => {
              logging.fire('event in event',() => {
                   console.log('event in event fired');
             });              
            console.log('do something1');
        });
          console.log('something1 outside');
        return;
    } 
    if (!param1.hello) {
        logging.fire('hello does not exist', () => {
            console.log('do something2');
        });
        return;
    }

    console.log('here is the final');
    return;
}

const logging = {
    fire: (event, callback) => {
        console.log('event fired: ' + event);
        return callback && callback();
    }
}

func1({})
```

PS: this link might help. That shall explain how javascript resolve the problem.
[Link](https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2016/03/14/wrapping-your-head-around-async-programming/)